# Dealing with JSON in HTML forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm asking this because I'm using a trick that works but I think my be problematic in the future.

I generate a html form in php using SimpleXML and DOM to manage the source (a html file with all forms needed). So I got my form and got to fill some properties. Here is an example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="arquivo_tipos" value="{arquivo_tipos}" />
```

{arquivos_tipos} is a JSON string, won't work inside double-quotes. However, if I create the source code like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="arquivo_tipos" value='{arquivo_tipos}' />
```

After being processed by php, it will return to double-quotes (I pick the form from a lot as a xml node). So my solution is replacing the property with this kind of script:

```
html = html.replace('"{arquivo_tipos}"', '\'[{"ext":"jpg","nome":"Imagem JPEG"},{"ext":"jpeg","nome":"Imagem JPEG"},{"ext":"gif","nome":"Bitmap GIF"},{"ext":"png","nome":"Imagem PNG"}]\'');
```

This is JavaScript, but in php I use the same trick with str_replace.

The point is, this is the final code, so it works, but smells like it will fails in the future if another process take this result. Is there a better way, a right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use php **htmlspecialchars** function, it can escape

```
double-quotes to &quot;
single-quotes to &#039;
```

https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: For text is a good solution, but the string is a JSON declaration, I don't think will parse by JavaScript or php by a request.